# Should I use a tag against its definition?

Tags: discussion, support

I'm trying to master charting on the web and I'm working with SVG components. Some of the elements that it can process is *path* and *circle*. When I ask a question that's very *circle* specific, I'd add that as one of the tags. However, when I came to a question specific to *path*, I read in the description that it's meant to treat **file** locations.

So, should I add *path* as a tag (because the question is about a path) or should I skip it (because the tag isn't meant for that)?

In this particular case, we might go for e.g. svg-path but what if (and this is a strictly theoretical consideration) there's no such tag (for another type of element) or if the question is about path in general (for svg and any other graphical context) but not relating to a file's location?

Comment: No, you should honor the definition of the tag as it currently sits.  You can create a new tag for the other kind of path.  With meta discussion, you could also rename the old tag to something like `file-path` for even less ambiguity.  See also [meta-tag:tag-disambiguation]

Comment: Most of the time less tags are better anyway. There exist many ambiguous tags.

Comment: circle seems like a pointless tag. Are there really circle experts watching the tag so they can answer circle-related questions about any language?

Comment: it's a meta tag and should probably be burned, as per the reason pointed out by @ThisSuitIsBlackNot

Answer (score 2):

> Should I use a tag against its definition?

No, you shouldn't.

There are many ambiguous tags existing at Stack Overflow, that don't relate to particular meanings without more context (meta tags as [@ThisSuitIsBlackNot points out in their comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315662/should-i-use-a-tag-against-its-definition/315669#comment300097_315662)).

Anyways asking with less tags and making a question more clear within it's content is the better way to do.

As pointed out by others meta tags like this one you mentioned, aren't very helpful for research or attracting interest in your questions.